# How to center images in a footer

Tags: css

Novice here! I'm looking to adjust some code for this site: http://www.lakeofstars.org

The footer area at the base of each page contains a series of logos. The ideal is to ensure that the logo images in the footer display correctly on mobile (if they are too large, some of the logos drop down below the designated footer background), but also to get them to center correctly on desktop - as you'll see, they are currently nudged to the left.

Here's the code as it stands:

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:140px;           /* Height of the footer */
    background:#ffffff;
    border-top: solid 3px #ffc600;
    background-image:url(img/global/footer.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position:bottom;
}


#footer .structure {
    height: 140px;
    width: 94%;
}

#footer .structure li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    float: left;
}

#footer .structure li img {
    height: 65px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `float: left;` from `#footer .structure li`.
Try to use `line-height` and `vertical-align: middle;` for vertical aligment and `text-align: center;` for horizontal:

```
#footer .structure {
    text-align: center;
}
#footer .structure ul {
    line-height: 140px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#footer .structure li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or you can use [flexbox technique](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:140px;
    background:#ffffff;
    border-top: solid 3px #ffc600;
    background-image:url(img/global/footer.gif) scroll 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position:bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add for `#footer .structure ul` - `text-align: center;`

remove for `#footer .structure li` -  `float: left`

```
#footer .structure ul {
   text-align: center; < -- add
}
#footer .structure li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
   /* float: left;*/ <-- remove

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove width:auto  ... give values in percentage....

```
#footer .structure li img
```